# Eclipse wont resolve LWJGL reference (.jar)

Tags: java, eclipse, reference, dependencies, lwjgl

This is related to ([Attach the Source in Eclipse of a jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15180411/attach-the-source-in-eclipse-of-a-jar))

I'm trying to use the LWJGL libraries (specifically `org.lwjgl.opengl.jar`).

The problem is that the import (`import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display`) will not resolve properly:

> the import org cannot be resolved

. On trying to open the classes in `org.jwlg.opengl` under "Referenced Libraries", I find:

> Source not found
>
> The source attachment does not contain the source for the file XXX

I added the opengl.jar by doing this:

> Right click on the project->BuildPath->Configure Build
>   Path->Libraries->Add External Jars

Here is everything I have tried to fix:

- Removed the reference and re-added it
- Cleaned the project (Project > clean). (didn't work)
- I tried using Java Source Attacher
  (https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/java-source-attacher) but it isn't compatible with my version of Eclipse
- Imported the `org.lwjgl.opengl.jar` file as a project and attaching it to the reference as the source, but it hasn't worked.

I have been downloading the library from https://www.lwjgl.org/customize

This is a possible solution but I don't understand the answer at all, could someone explain? [LWJGL jar not accesable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28080220/lwjgl-jar-not-accesable)

Comment: @Alex I gave up and downloaded IntelliJ after seeing that it wasn't simple in Eclipse (personally I don't like eclipse anyway).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`org.lwjgl.opengl.Display` is from LWJGL 2, you downloaded LWJGL 3. See the guide: https://www.lwjgl.org/guide for its replacement.

Comment: @TurgidWizard you haven't added the jar in the way that the guide says to: https://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl3-wiki/wiki/1.2.-Install#eclipse